# Adding and deleting to Core Data SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to display a heart that when I tap on it I add an item to my favorite view like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(entity: Favorites.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]) var favoritesItems: FetchedResults<Favorites>

let title1 = "Random title1"
let title2 = "Random title2"
@State private var saved1 = false
@State private var saved2 = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title1)
            Image(systemName: saved ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.saved1.toggle()
                    self.addItem(item: title1)
                    // Deleting?
                }

            Text(title2)
            Image(systemName: saved ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.saved2.toggle()
                    self.addItem(item: title2)
                    // Deleting?
                }
        }
    }
    func addItem(item: String) {
        let newItem = Favorites(context: managedObjectContext)
        newItem.title = item
    }
    // Function to delete that item??
}
```

How can i create a function that delete that item even

Comment: It seems like you have two separate items, but a single `saved` state variable. So the heard is shown only when this single state variable is changed. There is nothing stopping you from  adding the same item multiple times every time you tap on the heart button. You probably want to set the image to to be on if the actual item is saved to favourites. But your requirements aren't clear from this question.

Comment: I can actually manage my State in order to switch only how the heart is displayed (empty or filled) but my problem is that when I add my item on core data i cannot delete it except on my favorite view with a delete slider. All I want to do is something like Instagram where you tap on a heart to add to core data and tap again to delete it

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but you have a fetch request for Favorites, but you aren't using that to drive your display. How do you know which entity you are deleting? Your code just shows hardcoded values.

Comment: Sorry if it's not that clear but you actually get the point, I'm adding the title to my managedObjectContext and it works fine but after that I completely lose it...I don't even know how that data is stored and how to access it after being added.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Yes. Use the items to create the list, and when tapping on the heart, toggle the favourited state of the item.

Comment: I already made a list that display those items but how can I remove that specific item in my core data?

Comment: `managedObjectContext.delete(<your entity>)`

Comment: It's a lot more useful if you post your actual code when asking a question. If you've already made a list, then post the code for your list.

Comment: I can delete my nsobject using .onDelete but it's not what i'm looking for...all I want to do is to use a button instead. When I call managedObjectContext.delete how can I pass it my entity? After my addItem function, how can I delete that object that I akready added from my core data?